# Can we blow Conch?

Tags: scripture, belief, rituals

Susumna Naadi gets activated when a conch is blown. As per Hindu tradition during aarthi a conch is being blown and during death it is used. Generally if we blow a conch the respiratory tract will be clean because we leave air out thru conch from the inhaled one thru nose. Has it been mentioned in any scripture that conch should not be blown at ordinary times?